# what browser is document.layers sniffing?

Tags: javascript, browser-detection

I am looking at some JS code from the 20th century, and they are using `document.layers` in code that is trying to get the current key code. What browser are they sniffing for?

i am about to replace the code with something like this:

```
var fn = function(event){
  event = event || window.event;
  var code = event.charCode || event.keyCode;
}
```

but i am afraid of breaking something arcane and releasing the evil

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`document.layers` exists in Netscape 4 and holds all `<layer>` and `<ilayer>` elements.
It was an early precursor to true DHTML.

For more information, see [here](http://oopweb.com/JavaScript/Documents/jsintro/Volume/part9/part9.htm). (Ten years old)

Comment: "Gee, Mr. Peabody, this code is really old and crufty. Is it from ancient Babylonia?" ... "Sherman! Quick! To the WayBack Machine! We must save civilization from the BLINK tag!" ... "Gasp!"  Stay tuned for next week's exciting episode.

Comment: my JVM ran out of memory after i made the replacement with newer code, hopefully that will be the extent of the arcane evil.

Comment: Firefox crashed when you replaced some Javascript? How could that happen?

Comment: nope, it wasnt the jvm, firefox crashed in the evil way where it appears to be running but isnt.

Comment: not when i replaced some javascript, but when i replaced some _utterly evil_ javascript.

Comment: The Javascript you replaced shouldn't make a difference.  What (and where) was it?

Answer (score 3):

Netscape 4 is not able to display any modern web-page due to it's total lack of CSS support - so if you drop the support for this browser then you are not breaking anything that isnt already broken.